# wrapping C++, How to do different classes operation in cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to wrap a c++ class with cython , where  the class uses another class as input for operator overloading. I don't know how to define the another class type in the python part. I wrote both pxd and pyx file for each class, and imported the Size one into Point. But failed to compile,.I upload the codes here https://github.com/YuboHe/PointSize, Somebody plz give a glimpse and leave me a hint, how to make the operation work, Much appreciation

here are two classes, where Point uses Size as a input for operator overloading

In Point.h

```
friend Point operator+(const Size& sz,const Point& pnt);
```

corresponding pxd file

```
cdef Point operator+(const Size& sz,const Point& pnt)
```

In the python definition part, I wrote like this, but it always gives me an error as [can not convert object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4nDI.png)

```
def __add__(left,right):
        cdef PyPoint pypt
        cdef Point pt
        if isinstance(left,PyPoint):
            if isinstance(right,PyPoint):
                pt = left.cpoint[0] + right.cpoint[0]
                pypt = PyPoint(pt.x,pt.y)
                return pypt
            elif isinstance(right,PySize):
                pt = left.cpoint[0] + right.csize[0] 
                pypt = PyPoint(pt.x,pt.y)
                return pypt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Cython that your object is a `PyPoint`. Do this using a type cast, which is [described in the documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/language_basics.html#checked-type-casts).

```
if isinstance(left,PyPoint):
    if isinstance(right,PyPoint):
         pt = (<PyPoint>left).cpoint[0] + (<PyPoint>right).cpoint[0]
```

Alternatively you could skip the `isinstance`s and do `(<PyPoint?>left)`, which throws a `TypeError` if the type isn't right. You'd catch the error and try other options.

Finally you can assign to a typed variable. Again, this throws a `TypeError` if the types don't match:

```
cdef PyPoint right_pt
# ...
right_pt = right # catch the error if needed...
right_pt.cpoint[0] # is OK
```